# Help with triple piston extender on a cave door

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want a triple piston extender for the final block retraction on my cave door but I’m a bit tight on space. The double extender already powers one of the pistons as is so I’m guessing I have to incorporate the triple extender with the double. No idea how I’m supposed to do it though. It would be nice to have it push a redstone lamp that gets powered in the closing position but I think that is aiming a bit high. Any ideas?

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJnrR.jpg)

Comment: world download if it helps (18w22c) http://www.mediafire.com/file/7727674vmwu5s5l/Flat+19A1.zip

Comment: I've been watching this for a while.  I have attempted it a few different ways but have been unsuccessful.  Quite the challenge.  A handful of very nice contraptions.  Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: I figured out the triple piston extender pretty much right after i posted this. It is a bit sensitive to update order but other than that it works great. http://www.mediafire.com/file/7km3cgma3mbs076/Redstone_Void.zip/file

Comment: You should post that as an answer along with a basic explanation of the circuit.  Then you can accept your own answer after a small wait period.  Possibly helps other players, gives you some points, and marks the question as answered.